# Resize LVM using Bash script

Tags: bash, lvm

Hello I am new on Linux and I have 3 LVM-s. I call them `LV_web1`,`LV_web2`,`LV_web3` My Volume group has 30 GB free space. Each of LVM has 1 GB free space. When the free space of each LVM become 100MB I want to extend and increase it by 1GB.

> I want to do that using script.

Comment: Isn't 100 MB a bit too little? File systems don't perform well when they are almost full.